# Blackberry (java development) invoking calendar entry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, calendar

I basically followed the guide to populate an event here on Blackberry's website : http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Open_new_populated_calendar_entry_565481_11.jsp

My app runs fine on my emulator until I use this line in the code:

Invoke.invokeApplication( Invoke.APP_TYPE_CALENDAR, new CalendarArguments( CalendarArguments.ARG_NEW, e ) )

When I use this, the emulator does not even finish loading and I get an error :

```
Application.getApplication line:2556 -> Source not found.
```

I am also getting a warning beside the problematic line, eclipse is saying the following :

```
Signing Required: RIM Blackberry Apps API (0x52424200): Protected Class net.rim.blackberry.api.invoke.Invoke    VeventDecoder.java  /Calendar/src/mypackage line 165    BlackBerry Protected API
```

I am using the latest Blackberry plugin for eclipse.

Can anyone help me fix this problem? Google has not been very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: "latest Blackberry plugin" is pretty vague, and becomes more vague as time passes.  Could you specify a specific version?  Also, what version of BlackBerry OS are you targeting?  What error do you get in the emulator? It looks like you're getting a stack trace if it is trying to show you a line of code, so there should be an exception named, and possibly a message attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Signing Required' means that you are using an API that requires you to sign your application with a set of BlackBerry Signing Keys, in order to run your application on a physical device. Invoking another RIM application is one of these cases.

You can apply for a set of BlackBerry signing keys from RIM, they are free, see here: https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/

Note the drop down, if you are developing a java application set it to 'BlackBerry Smartphone Code Signing Key'

You will receive emailed instructions on how to import the keys into the IDE you are using for development.

You will also receive three (3) further emails, each containing a different signing key, you will need to import all 3 keys into your development environment. I have mentioned this, because this is were many people have fallen in this signing issue, by only importing the key from one of these 3 emails.